# Parallel transaction blockchaon causing replacement error or nonce too low error

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum

I want to perform several transaction from an account at a time , basically calling different smart contract using golang (not geth , using go binding for Smart contract interaction). when i carry out this transaction, the "Transaction replacement error" or "Nonce too low" error occurs,but i dont want them to be replaced instead each transaction should be carried out .

What already being tried :
1) Periodic increasing counter for increasing nonce for each transaction and binding it with singing message. 
2 Getting last pending nonce and using it for next transaction (But it is not helping since if we want several trasnaction , each calling 3 different Smart contract at a time, apprently ends up in one of two above error only).

reference link : https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Native-DApps:-Go-bindings-to-Ethereum-contracts (procedure iam using for Smart Contarct interaction)

Comment: Your first idea is right. Get the right nonce, and then for each transaction you send, increase it by one.

Comment: but this does not work , if there are many transactions the counter increases very much and no transaction recorded in blockchain .

Comment: You'll probably need to share your code if you need help debugging it.

Comment: thanks for the help , but i cannot share the code ,Thank you